# Missing father for Mary Goldie born 1891?

Tags: scotland, 1890s, lanarkshire

I have a person in my family tree called Mary Goldie who was born in 1891 and I don't have her father. Her mothers name was also Mary Goldie. I have tried births but shes illegitimate and marriages doesn't have a father and I've tried deaths.

Where else could I look?

Answer (score 3):

The other place that you could check is the [Kirk Sessions records](https://www.genguide.co.uk/source/kirkchurch-sessions-scotland/116/) for the parish where her mother was living when she was born (you should have the parish from the birth certificate).

Although many have been digitised, at present these are not available online. You would have to visit one of the [local archives](https://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/research/guides/church-court-records-online) in Scotland that have access to the collection.

---

There are [plans](https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/content/when-will-kirk-session-and-other-church-court-records-be-available) to make these (and other court) records more widely available via the [ScotlandsPeople](https://www.scotlandspeople.gov.uk/) website. You may already be familiar with this site if that's where you obtained the birth, marriage and death certificates.

It may be worth signing up for their email updates so that you are kept informed of the latest additions to records on the site.